# How to return runtime duration in milliseconds in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have many steps in 1 function and want to get how long it takes to complete, so I tried:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
..do step1
..do step2
..
var end = new Date().getTime();
```

so I get "end - start"  <-- how can I get this into miliseconds?

Comment: You need to explain what is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It is in milliseconds. You just need to do `end - start` and you have the runtime in milliseconds.

`var runtime = end - start;`

Here is what `getTime()` does:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Each time you call `getTime()` you're getting the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970.